# use queryInterface api in sequelize to select * from a table

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-cli, sequelize-typescript

I am trying to use queryInterface api in sequelize to select * from a table
I know I can use bulkInsert ... based on the documentation but I can not see any function for selecting the data

```
queryInterface.bulkInsert('Users', [{
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Doe',
      email: 'example@example.com',
      createdAt: new Date(),
      updatedAt: new Date()
    }]);
  },
```

Am I missing anything or it is not provided?

Comment: You can do a raw query. `queryInterface.sequelize.query('select * from table')`